how to put a search field in the List.Accordion component? (Prop - List.Accordion (Paper) - React Native)
I want to place a search field and a sort field in the List.Accordion component of the React Native Paper library, as shown in the image below.

note: I saw that the List.Accordion component can receive another ReactNode as a prop through the props, left and right,
as mentioned in the following link:
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/List/ListAccordion
but when trying to style them I encounter difficulties with it.
What is the best way to do this? create my own custom component or try to customize the already mentioned component?

As I was unable to customize the component the way I wanted, I chose to create my own custom component,
